# Normalization and Design

Tags: normalization

I have a design question. 
There are three tables: Users, Posts, and offers.
Offers and Posts are related based on the postid, and users and posts are related on user id.
Now, users will posts something, it could be something to buy or sell. Now users make an offer to buy a post that is being posted. One user can offer to buy multiple posts. So this means one user can have multiple offers for multiple posts. How can i achieve that a user has many offers for different posts. One user can have offer only one posts (meaning there will be only one offer for one post).

Looks simple but am kind a lost, any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are describing a relationship like this:

[Users]1---A---m[Posts]1---B---m[Offers]

[Users]1---C---m[Offers]

The key for relationship A (one-to-many) is userId; the key for relationship B (one-to-many) is postId; and the key for relationship (one-to-many) C is userId.

I think you are missing relationship C in your description.  This will require Offers to have two foreign keys; userId and postId.  The combination of userId and postId can also be the primary key for Offers because that combination should always be unique.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. So to reconfirm, if i make a composite key of userid and postid in offers table, this should work on what am thinking. All am confused is, i want to get all offers made by a user for all posts.

Comment: I would add the composite key of userid + postid, but I would also add individual foreign keys for userid and postid.  To get all of the offers for a user the query would be something like "select * from Offers where userid = 'thisid'.  If you have the foreign keys defined and you use an ORM then getting a User would automatically contain a collection of Offers.

Comment: Do we need another table for the composite key or can i just add userID and postid in the offers table as a composite key. Let me know and thanks for the help.

Comment: The composite key would just be in the Offers table.  To be clear, you have a separate columns in the Offers table for userid and postid.  When you define your primary key (clustered) you just use both columns. And then you would define two other keys (non-clustered) one for the userid and the other for the postid.

Comment: Ok. But i do have an offerid as a primary key in offers table which has an identity column. So to understand clearly:  postid + userid ( Composite key which will be a PK) and another  say PID(for post ID) as a foreign key refereing to Post table, and then uID ( for user ID) refereing to users table ( as foreign keys). Do i remove offerid which is used a PK in offers table? thanks

Comment: You can go either way with the primary key, keeping it the way you have or using the method I suggested, dependent on the design of the system. You do not need the offerid column unless there is some other relationship or query in the database that requires it.  For example, another table requires a foreign key that links it back to the Offers. If it is not required I would eliminate the offerid and go with the composite as it maintains another "business rule" that a User can only have a single offer per Post. Your understanding of the foreign keys is correct.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. One more question, it make a difference if i add unique index on userid and postid in offers table keeping offerid as PK as there is another table that has a fk on this offers table on offerid. Thanks

Comment: You have to way the pros and cons to make your decision on making userid and postid unique.  The pro is that it maintains the relationship of a User having only 1 Offer per Post on the database server.  The con is that it is another index for the server to maintain which may not be used for any queries and could slow down inserts. If you are only using it to maintain that relationship you may want to forgo adding another index and maintaining that relationship in the application.

Comment: Thanks Kevin and i would go with adding PK of offerid and making userid and postid as unique index so that offerid would be used for another relation in a table. Appreicate the help!!!

Comment: I have about 8 tables to look at, would you be able to look at them and suggest i am doing some silly things? If so, where do i send them? Thanks